# "what does the 1 to 10 mean?" FOR number ← 1 TO 10

Tags: algorithms, loops

"what does the to 10 mean?"  FOR number ← 1 TO 10

Comment: And also how would this be translated into python? Thanks :)

Comment: From context, it probably means that the following is block is executed first for number=1, then for number=2, ..., finally for number=10. I'm sure you can translate it into python, though that's off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, this is typically written

```python
for number in range(1, 10):  # or range(1, 11) depending on interpretation
    pass  # do stuff here
```

where `pass` is replaced with the block you want to execute.

Note that I wrote `range(1,10)` which gives

```
number = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

in turn, i.e. the endpoint (10) is *exclusive*.  It could mean that the `1 TO 10` should be interpreted *inclusive*, i.e.

```
number = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

but out of context, this is difficult to say.

In C-like languages, this often looks like

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Again, maybe the `i < 10` should be `i <= 10`.

The syntax in the exercise looks a lot like Pascal, which uses

```pascal
begin
   for number := 1 to 10 do
   begin
      // do stuff here
   end;
end.
```

which I believe is *inclusive*.